# Select item in Listview programmatically, which is bound to a datatable and default is in sorted order?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, datatable

I have a datatable and it is bound to a listview

> listview.ItemsSource = datatable.DefaultView;
>   and 
>   datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC";

When I change "st" is sorted and reflected to the UI immediately ...

How I select a listview item programmatically?

I tried this but its not working, it selects a different item:

```
string query = "id = " + "'" + ID.ToString() + "'";
DataRow[] _row = datatable.Select(query);
if (_row.Length > 0)
{
      DataRow row = _row[0];
      int index = datatable.Rows.IndexOf(row);
      listview.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you add '' ' " to you query?

Comment: According to MSDN:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you table should contain a column called id, and you don't really need to add those " ' " to your query

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Because its integer value that's by nothing important

Comment: it is important. When you call the ToString method then it is not integer anymore. And adding " ' " to it, it will be '002' instead of 002

Comment: ok understand thanks

Comment: @NawedNabiZada can you help me about my problem ?

Comment: Well, again do you have a columnd called id ? if yes the try with var query = "id =="+ID.ToString();

Comment: its "==" not working

Comment: Can you make an edit, and show the datatable ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada  this is work fine when a remove this "datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC" code ... so here is issue related to that..  when I use Sord its not working properly and select difference..  because sort is only apply on defaultview not in datatable so I need solution how to select listview item through id or some thing like that...

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong when can't see all of your code, but below you can see a working sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the cs file:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _datatable1 = new DataTable();
    _datatable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
    _datatable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
    _datatable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("st", typeof(int)));
    _datatable1.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC";
    LsVTest.ItemsSource = _datatable1.DefaultView;

    _datatable1.Rows.Add(1, "row1", 6);
    _datatable1.Rows.Add(2, "row2", 2);
    _datatable1.Rows.Add(3, "row3", 8);
    _datatable1.Rows.Add(4, "row4", 4);
    _datatable1.Rows.Add(5, "row5", 9);
    _datatable1.Rows.Add(6, "row6", 6);

    _datatable1 = _datatable1.DefaultView.ToTable();
    _datatable1.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC";
    LsVTest.ItemsSource = _datatable1.DefaultView;
}

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = "id=3";
    var rows = _datatable1.Select(query);
    if (rows.Length <= 0) return;
    var row = rows[0];
    var index = _datatable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
    LsVTest.SelectedIndex = index;
}

private void ButtonBase_OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow[] Rows = _datatable1.Select("id=" + 3);
    Rows[0]["st"] = 10;
    _datatable1 = _datatable1.DefaultView.ToTable();
    _datatable1.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC";
    LsVTest.ItemsSource = _datatable1.DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you are doing but, here is a sample which works perfectly:

**VIEW:**

```
    <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
            <ListView x:Name="LsVTest">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="st" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=st}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <Button Content="Select row2" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
</Button>
    <Button Content="Change values" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick1"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

**CODE:**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private DataTable _datatable1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _datatable1 = new DataTable();
        _datatable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
        _datatable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
        _datatable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("st", typeof(string)));

        _datatable1.Rows.Add(1, "row1", "st1");
        _datatable1.Rows.Add(2, "row2", "st2");
        _datatable1.Rows.Add(3, "row3", "st3");
        _datatable1.Rows.Add(4, "row4", "st4");
        _datatable1.Rows.Add(5, "row5", "st5");
        _datatable1.Rows.Add(6, "row6", "st6");
        _datatable1.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC";
        LsVTest.ItemsSource = _datatable1.DefaultView;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = "id=2" ;
        var rows = _datatable1.Select(query);
        if (rows.Length <= 0) return;
        var row = rows[0];
        var index = _datatable1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
        LsVTest.SelectedIndex = index;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _datatable1.Rows[3][0]= 6;
        _datatable1.Rows[3][1] = "row6";
        _datatable1.Rows[3][2] = "st6";
        LsVTest.ItemsSource = _datatable1.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It still works.

Comment: hey add third coloum  st and sort on st "_datatable1.DefaultView.Sort = "st DESC";'  and enter some value like "3,4,5" ok after this change value at run time 3=6 , 4 =9 and than click ButtonBase_OnClick and value is coming wrong or it select different item

Comment: I would say add some code, it is still working here. even with the third column, I don't really understand which values you want to change at runtime. st values, name values or id values ?

Comment: I am changing the st value at run time.. and sort is on st value only

Comment: Check my code, I added the other values as well and it still works.

Comment: try this not working:- https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwoqfsg1dvkhp3o/New%20Text%20Document.txt?dl=0

Comment: hhmm... add this LsVTest.ItemsSource = _datatable1.DefaultView; after AcceptChanges, and it will work. One thing you should be aware of, is the databinding. This sample I provided is very basic, you have to update your source manually ever time there is a change. That's what you are forgetting here. I would recommend you MVVM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx